# EventListener Freezing (Java)

Tags: java, swing, jframe

Alright so, my issue is that the mouseMoved is frozen when you drag the mouse, which is one of the methods in MouseMotionListener ( mouseMoved, and mouseDragged ). I think maybe the mouseDragged is freezing mouseMoved, if anyone can help me so that it doesn't do that, that would be greatly wonderful.

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.event.MouseMotionListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.lang.Runnable;
import java.awt.RenderingHints;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Color;

public class Window extends JFrame implements MouseMotionListener, Runnable {
    protected static int xWindow = 640;
    protected static int yWindow = 480;
    private Image dbi;
    private Graphics dbg;
    private int xMouse;
    private int yMouse;

    public void paint( Graphics g ) {
        dbi = createImage( getWidth(), getHeight() );
        dbg = dbi.getGraphics();
        paintComponent( dbg );
        g.drawImage( dbi, 0, 0, this );
    }

    public void paintComponent( Graphics g ) {
        Graphics2D g2d = ( Graphics2D ) g;
        g2d.setRenderingHint( RenderingHints.KEY_TEXT_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_TEXT_ANTIALIAS_ON );
        g2d.setColor( Color.RED );
        g2d.drawString( "Mouse X: " + xMouse + " | Y: " + yMouse, 15, 40 );

        repaint();
    }

    public void mouseDragged( MouseEvent e ) {
        e.consume();
    }

    public void mouseMoved( MouseEvent e ) {
        xMouse = e.getX();
        yMouse = e.getY();
        e.consume();
    }

    public void run() {
        while ( true ) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep( 1 );
            } catch( Exception e ) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

You're calling `repaint` from `paintComponent` which causes the following method call chain to repeat indefinitely:

```
paint -> (manual call to) paintComponent
```

To take advantage of Swing's optimized paint model, better not to do custom painting in top level containers such as `JFrame`. Extract all the paint functionality to a new `JComponent` or `JPanel` based class and override `paintComponent`. Swing will call `paintComponent` on `repaint` so no need to call directly. Don't forget to call `super.paintComponent(g)`.

Call `repaint` from within `mouseMoved`.

Also don't call `Thread.sleep`, this blocks the `EDT` and causes the UI to freeze. Swing provides its own [concurrency objects](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html) such as [Swing Timers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html).